# Creating column headers in CSV/TSV files using AWS Data Pipeline?

Tags: csv, amazon-web-services, export-to-csv, amazon-data-pipeline

I'm creating CSV & TSV files using AWS Data Pipeline. The files are creating just fine, but I can't figure out how to create files with column headers.

At first, I expected the headers to generate automatically based on the SQL query I'm running to get the export. That didn't work, but was ok.

Then I added a list of column definitions to the "column" attribute of the DefaultDataFormat3 feature/node.

```
{
  "escapeChar": "\\",
  "name": "DefaultDataFormat3",
  "column": [
    "id INT",
    "field1 STRING",
    "field2 STRING"
  ],
  "columnSeparator": "|",
  "id": "DataFormatId_jEXqL",
  "type": "TSV",
  "recordSeparator": "\\n"
}
```

I still just get CSVs and TSVs with no header row in the export.

Comment: AWS Datapipeline is very poorly documented. Most places it's difficult to understand what the field is supposed to do.

Comment: Having the same problem... did you ever get a solution?

Comment: I did not, @joeB1 : (

Answer (score 7):

I ran across a [blog post](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/aws-pro-tip-export-data-from-rds-csv-format-using-pipelines-bejda) explaining a solution for this. If you are using a query for your data you can add the column names as the first result:

```
SELECT 'firstName', 'lastName', 'email'
UNION ALL
SELECT firstName, lastName, email
FROM users
```

Comment: This is a most excellent solution. But, AWS should fix it too! : )

Comment: Agreed. One downside to this solution is that you have to convert everything to strings or SQL complains about the mismatched column types.

Comment: Clever, much cleaner than adding another processing step. Thanks.